# nano via SSH commands not working

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, nano

I logged into my VPS server via SSH from my remote computer, a macbook pro.  I run the command `visudo` to edit a config file using nano, when I am done editing the file I attempt to exit using `control x` or `^x` (same thing).  However instead of prompting me for if I want to save, like I have read, it just says this at the bottom...

```
--^X mode (^]^D^E^F^I^K^L^N^O^Ps^U^V^Y)
```

I can't even exit nano, and when I try other commands like `control g` nothing happens.

How do I exit nano and save the file?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not running `nano`, you're running `vim`.

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> to put vim in the background and get back to your shell (you can kill vim with `kill %1`).

Then `export EDITOR=nano` and `visudo` again to edit using nano.

(To instead save and exit in Vim, use <kbd>Esc</kbd> to exit "^X mode", then press uppercase Z twice to save and exit).

Comment: Thank you very much, I would like to know however what to do about the down votes I received on this question, I spent about 2 hours researching this and could not figure it out, I feel like it is an honest and well stated question.  And now I can't ask more questions either.  I would just like some advice from an experienced user such as yourself.

Comment: The question itself is very well stated, it's just that stackoverflow.com is meant for programming questions ([superuser.com](http://superuser.com) is the equivalent for software questions, and there's even a [askubuntu.com](http://askubuntu.com/) for Ubuntu specific questions). Whether having multiple sites like this is useful is another matter, but that's how it is.